# Slow DB2 connection on .NET

Tags: c#, .net, database, db2, database-connection

I'm working on a project where we're gonna fetch data from a DB2 database. 
I've been testing with both the ibm provider and simple odbc and with both approaches the connection open method is very very slow.

If I try doing the same thing with Java and the IBM jdbc driver, it is a lot faster.

Does anyone have any tips on how to improve performance in .NET ?

Answer (score 3):

Faster, slower, they are all relative terms, relative to what you know.

1. Read this for background:

   [Does sybase 15 support the bcp api in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859076/does-sybase-15-support-the-bcp-api-in-java/4003954#4003954)
2. Fine, JDBC is faster than ODBC, because IBM did a good job of implementing it.  Sure, you can check the configuration of your ODBC vs your JDBC, and improve it a little.
3. Both JDBC and ODBC are excruciatingly slow compared to using IBM CLient Library.  Get your hands on that, it is free.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I see that i was a bit unclear in my original post, on .NET i did the test with the api provided through the client library and the regular odbc, both were very slow. On java i used the jar provided through the client library it was seconds faster than the .net equivalent.

Comment: The Client Library through Java is news to me.  From the detail in my other post, you can see why architecturally, jar would be slow.  I can't say that Client Library+.Net "should" be faster or not; it could well be the usual abomination.  But it is alleged to be "native".  I architect for Java but I can't help you with .Net.  Sorry.